# benchmarking bottle and flask - what is wrong?

Tags: python, flask

I am attempting to benchmark flask and bottle to make some new project decision.  I am seeing bottle fail miserably while flask seems to work.  I cannot believe that the frameworks are so far apart (are they?!).  I am guess I am doing something simple and wrong.  I quite cannot figure it out why.

**Client**

First step I am attempting to do a benchmark using [Wrk](https://github.com/wg/wrk) as the client to generate load.  My Wrk cmdline looks like this

```
./wrk -c 20 -d 30 -t 10 --latency http://localhost:8888/hello/world
```

**Bottle**

The Bottle sample server looks like this

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from bottle import route, run, template

@route('/hello/<name>')
def index(name):
        return template('<b>Hello {{name}}</b>!', name=name)

run(host='localhost', port=8888)
```

The output from the benchmark is

```
Running 30s test @ http://localhost:8888/hello/world
  10 threads and 20 connections
  Thread Stats   Avg      Stdev     Max   +/- Stdev
    Latency     6.07s     4.44s   13.38s    55.49%
    Req/Sec   184.27    311.26     1.33k    73.56%
  Latency Distribution
     50%    7.29s 
     75%    7.42s 
     90%   13.38s 
     99%   13.38s 
  34208 requests in 30.02s, 5.61MB read
  Socket errors: connect 0, read 0, write 0, timeout 177
Requests/sec:   1139.47
Transfer/sec:    191.40KB
```

I am seeing a whole bunch of errors on the server logs (related to the timeouts I guess)

```
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 56893)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 284, in _handle_request_noblock
    self.process_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 310, in process_request
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 323, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 640, in __init__
    self.finish()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 693, in finish
    self.wfile.flush()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 303, in flush
    self._sock.sendall(view[write_offset:write_offset+buffer_size])
error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

**Flask**

Now I repeated the same test with flask

Flask server

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/hello/<name>")
def hello(name):
        return "Hello {0}!".format(name)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(port=8888)
```

Now the output from the run

```
Running 30s test @ http://localhost:8888/hello/world
  10 threads and 20 connections
  Thread Stats   Avg      Stdev     Max   +/- Stdev
    Latency    10.83ms  691.95us  22.49ms   93.54%
    Req/Sec   187.71     22.99   285.00     83.73%
  Latency Distribution
     50%   10.74ms
     75%   11.02ms
     90%   11.42ms
     99%   12.52ms
  55203 requests in 30.00s, 8.69MB read
Requests/sec:   1840.00
Transfer/sec:    296.48KB
```

This looks more "normal".  I am doing this on my laptop (i5/8G/Mint).  No special installation of either frameworks (pip install).

Scratching my head on this one!

Comment: i'm not familiar with bottle but you might try to run the server on 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost

Comment: My hosts file has 127.0.0.1 mapped to localhost.  How would using IP be any different?  BTW tried it no improvement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both Flask and Bottle are *WSGI application frameworks*; they let you build a web application through the WSGI protocol.

To make it easier for you to develop your code, both frameworks come with a built-in, basic WSGI *server*, so you don't need to install something separate just to test your code. Neither server is suitable for production use however; one of the reasons being that they are not set up for heavy loads, for example.

I suspect you wanted to test how the *frameworks* stack up, and not their basic development servers. Use a proper [WSGI deployment](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/deploying/) to test the framework against, and make sure you use the same configuration for both frameworks. Be careful not to end up testing the container (server)'s ability to handle load.